# how to stream from webcam opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, stream, ip, vlc

I need to stream the videos that my webcam capture to another computer (on VLC). However when I run my code;

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture.open("http://192.168.43.1:8080/out.h264")
while (vcap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=vcap.read()
    if ret== True:
        cv2.imshow("video",frame)
```

I get this error:

> [tcp @ 0000025946ef3040] Connection to tcp://192.168.43.1:8080 failed:
>   Error number -138 occurred

When I write 0 inside of the VideoCapture() Everything works fine, the video capturing starts. Therefore, I think the ip is wrong?..

Also I need to ask another question. Can I make a rtp stream with webcam? Or Do I need an IP cam? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please add details about your setup to your question!

Comment: what kind of details? Do you mean my whole code or my system?

Comment: That URL looks strange. Does it work in other softwares?